# fscanf a line separated by tab

Tags: c, io

```
fscanf(input_file, "%s\t%d\t%d", line, &x, &y);
```

The goal of this code is to read a line, the file should be

```
Double Cheese 4 10
```

Double Cheese and 4 are split by \t, 4 and 10 are also split by \t so like this

```
Double Cheese\t4\t10
```

"Double Cheese" is a string needed to be stored to line.

Comment: That won't work - `%s` treats **any and all** whitespace characters as a delimiter.  Use `fgets()` or `getline()` to read the entire line and parse the line in a separate step, either manually or with `strtok[_r]()`.

Comment: Add to the previous comment, to *always* check the return value of any input function.

Comment: Patrick Wong, what should happen if the line of input does not meet the criteria?

Comment: @AndrewHenle: `strtok` and similar functions seem inappropriate for this  as they do not support empty fields either.

Comment: There is no speak about empty fields.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `fscanf()`, read the *line* with `fgets()` or if available: `getline()`.

After reading the line, consider strong parsing techniques.  Look for the `'\t'`.  Allow `'\t'` as the first character. When parsing avoid assuming string length and its last character.  Test integer values for range. Detect trailing junk.
Example:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
  const char *s; // Not null character terminated
  size_t s_length;
  long x, y;
} sll;

// Return error flag
int parse_string_tab_int_tab_int(sll *z, const char *src) {
  *z = (sll) {.s = src, .s_length = strcspn(src, "\t")};
  src += z->s_length;
  if (src[0] != '\t') {
    return 1;
  }
  char *endptr;
  errno = 0;
  z->x = strtol(++src, &endptr, 10);
  if (src == endptr || errno || *endptr != '\t') {
    return 1;
  }
  src = endptr;
  z->y = strtol(++src, &endptr, 10);
  if (src == endptr || errno) {
    return 1;
  }
  // Consume optional trailing whitespace.
  while (isspace(*(unsigned char* )endptr)) {
    endptr++;
  }
  return (*endptr != '\0');
}
```

Usage example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char buf[BUFSIZ];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
    sll data;
    if (parse_string_tab_int_tab_int(&data, buf)) {
      puts("Fail"); // or other TBD code
    } else {
      printf("Food: %.*s %ld %ld\n", //
          (int) data.s_length, data.s, data.x, data.y);
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chqrlie Code corrected again - I sacked the editor.

Answer (score 1):

In the OP's posted code, the `%s` will stop at the first whitespace character (of any type). The menu is delimited by tabs, so we can use `%[]` to read up to the delimiter. And then the `%d` specs automatically filter this and the next whitespace.

Additionally, there is a leading space before `%[]` because this, and the `%c` format, do *not* automatically filter leading whitespace.

And robust code will always limit potential string overflow accidents and exploits, by giving the max characters to read.

Finally, always check that `scanf` family functions return the expected value: the number of items successfully converted. Here, it is used to drive the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    
int main(void) {
    
    int x, y;
    char line[100];
        
    FILE *input_file = fopen("menu.txt", "rt");
    if(input_file == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    while(fscanf(input_file, " %99[^\t]%d%d", line, &x, &y) == 3) {
        //       leading space^  ^length limit         expected^
        printf("%s ~ %d ~ %d\n", line, x, y);
    }
    fclose(input_file);
    return 0;
}
```

Input file (tab separated)

```
Single Cheese       4      10
Double Cheese       5      15
Triple Cheese       6      20
```

Program output

```
Single Cheese ~ 4 ~ 10
Double Cheese ~ 5 ~ 15
Triple Cheese ~ 6 ~ 20
```

Comment: "the %s will stop at the first whitespace character (of any type)." is more like: `"%s"` will scan and toss any whitespace, then scan and save non-white space and then will stop at the first whitespace character (of any type)".

Comment: Using `fscanf()` for this is  brittle: it cannot support empty fields, which the format allows